# Combining animate and load with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, load

I'm trying to slide out a `div`, and once complete, fade in content with a `.load` request.

I'm not sure why this is incorrect, but this stops the animate and load completely:

```
$('.films').click(function(){
    $('.content-home').animate({left: "+=150%"}, "slow", function(){
        $( ".wrapper" ).load( "films.php", function(){
                 $(this).fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

However, by reverting to this code, it still loads the content without any animation or fade:

```
$('.films').click(function(){
    $('.content-home').animate({left: "+=150%"}, "slow");
        $( ".wrapper" ).load( "films.php");
});
```

Would anyone know why the first example does not perform as requested?

Comment: Does the console output anything?

Comment: No errors, just a warning: `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Your code works. Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/K69xq/

Answer (score 0):

Use this for animate()

```
 $( 'content-home' ).animate({ opacity: 0.25, left: "+=50",height: "toggle"}, 
                      5000, 
                      "slow",
                      function() { 
                         // your remaining code
                      });
```